# How do i check whether a particular memcache key exists using unix command

Tags: php, unix, memcached, memcachedb

I am new to memcache. Memcache has been used for some queries. There is some problem with cache, and it seems memcache is not working properly. 
I need to check whether a particular memcache key is there in dump. My project is in php.

can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example on the homepage of the project:

```
telnet localhost 11211
get foo
```

You can also try a PHP client like http://code.google.com/p/phpmemcacheadmin/